# Intersection of cubes in 3D space

Tags: geometry, collision-detection

There are two cubes cubeA and cubeB. cubeA has 8 points and cubeB has 8 points. How do I check if the cubes are intersecting. Cubes are not aligned along any axis and they have different rotations.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you perhaps tell us what you have tried already?

Comment: Are you asking about a method that would solve this problem given a set of equations that describe the cubes?

Comment: @ImATurtle yes I want a method to solve

Comment: Well, if you have your typical equation-of-a-plane describing each of the 6 sides of the cubes, you can easily set those equations equal to each other, and although it's quite a tedious process, it gets the job done. There might be a clever way with inscribing each of the cubes inside of a sphere.. If the spheres themselves don't intersect, then it's obvious that the cubes are also non-intersecting. In the case that they do intersect, I'm sure you can use the size of the circle they form to tell whether the cubes are touching.. Some specific equations for consideration would be helpful